# Вопрос без счётчика голосов на закрытие в очереди на закрытие

Tags: поддержка, очередь-проверок, закрытие-вопросов

В описании очереди на закрытие сказано:

> Голосуйте, следует ли закрывать вопросы, за закрытие которых **уже есть голоса**

При этом иногда попадаются вопросы, для которых указана какая-то существующая причина закрытия, [например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/160430):

> [image: помечен]

однако на самом вопросе не видно цифры рядом с ссылкой `закрыть`, которая говорит о количестве имеющихся голосов:

> [image: действия]

Сначала я подумал, что такая ситуация возможна для вопросов с одним единственным голосом, но всё таки такие вопросы попадаются:

> [image: закрыть (1)]

С чем связано отсутствие цифры рядом с ссылкой `закрыть`, но наличие вопроса в очереди на закрытие?

Comment: тревога а не голос

Comment: @Grundy вполне может быть. Об этом где-то явно сказано или просто догадка?

Comment: скорее догадка: вполне логично, что тот кто шлет тревогу, еще не может голосовать, поэтому его голос не считается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@Grundy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy) после череды промахов ([возможно, специальных](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=36833839#36833839)) наконец-то [оказался прав](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5151/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5#comment19005_5151). :)

На MSE есть [ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159945/339911) модератора (правда с некоторой долей неуверенности) на подобный вопрос: [Questions with no close votes appearing in the close vote queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159944/questions-with-no-close-votes-appearing-in-the-close-vote-queue). И в нём сказано:

> Any time a user without the vote-to-close privilege flags the question for a canned vote-to-close reason, it is automatically added to the close votes review queue as a way of reviewing the flag.

Т.о. установка флага "должен быть закрыт" приводит к попаданию вопроса в очередь проверки на закрытие без установки явного голоса за закрытие.

Comment: а что за череда промахов?

Comment: @vp_arth см. в чате ранее по тексту.

Comment: Нипанятна жи! Ответ должен быть самодостаточным. У меня чувство, что я что-то пропустил, комплекс незавершённого действия)

Comment: @vp_arth не хочется делать ответ [т](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2_(%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0))[а](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90_(%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0))[к](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A_(%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0))[и](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98)[м](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C_(%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)).