# Как работает закрытие из очереди?

Tags: поддержка, очередь-проверок, закрытие-вопросов

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/171951

Почему в очереди голосов за закрытие 4, а на вопросе только 2?

[image: скриншот]

Этот вопрос не дубликат [Вопрос без счётчика голосов на закрытие в очереди на закрытие](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5151/178988%D0%AE), потому что там говорится о разнице в 1 голос, вызванной постановкой тревоги на вопрос, а здесь есть голоса непосредственно в очереди и разница даже не 1.

Comment: Очевидно, что жмакать "закрыть" в очереди проверок можно всем, а учитываются (влияют на закрытие) только те, у кого репа >= 3к.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, слывёт молва что отвечать в комментариях - моветон.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский откуда очевидно? Допускаю, что дело в одном, ответившем "выглядит нормально"

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Э... А разве очередь на закрытие становится доступна не одновременно с голосами за закрытие? Я думал, что "нулевые" голоса рождаются только в тревогах.

Comment: @Squidward, так в очереди ещё есть "Рекомендовать закрытие" кроме "Закрыть".

Comment: @Qwertiy В какой очереди?

Comment: @Squidward, не помню, но точно где-то есть)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вопрос без счётчика голосов на закрытие в очереди на закрытие](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5151/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%81%d1%87%d1%91%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Comment: @alexolut, нет, дополнил.

Comment: @Qwertiy не важно какая там разница в количестве, это количество обусловлено участниками, у которых нет 3к. И указанный у Вас вопрос был закрыт дважды кстати.

Comment: Судя по всему проблема в том, что в очереди голоса «Рекомендовать закрытие» отображаются как «Закрыть» ([более свежий пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/171951)). Может стоит это указать в вопросе? Стоит проверить локализацию, но вообще такой баг возникает и в английской версии:   https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208221/low-quality-review-queue-erroneously-showing-close-instead-of-recommended-clo