# Разное число закрытий в очереди проверок и в вопросе

Tags: дефект, очередь-проверок, закрытие-вопросов

[В проверке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/224459) вопроса на момент написания этого текста набралось аж шесть закрытий:

> [image]

Однако в самом вопросе их всего три:

> [image]

Это как вообще?

Comment: это норма :-) У трех участников, репутация меньше минимума, когда можно закрывать вопросы. Поэтому _реальных_ голосов, на момент публикации вопроса - всего 3

Comment: Ладно, [вот тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5424) пишут, что учитываются только голоса от юзеров с >=3к репы. но тогда почему они вообще могут жмать «Закрыть» в очереди проверок? Считаю это дефектом

Comment: @andreymal у них там кнопка "рекомендовать закрытие", а не закрыть, и это задокументировання фича: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work, "f you haven't earned the close privilege, you'll be offered a Recommend Close option instead - this carries no weight on its own, but puts the question in the Close Votes queue for privileged users to confirm or decline (see below)."

Comment: @PashaPash значит и здесь нужно писать «Рекомендовать закрытие», а не «Закрыть»

Comment: @andreymal если бы кнопки не было - не было бы способа хоть как-то сказать "да, вопрос низкого качества и его стоит закрыть (тем, у кого есть право закрывать вопросы)

Comment: @andreymal ну это уже вопрос к локализаторам :)

Comment: @alexolut ↑ :-)

Comment: @andreymal - вот enSO, там этот тип голоса явно называется Recommend Close: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18297206

Comment: @PashaPash когда местные локализаторы подтвердят проблему локализации, переделаю вопрос в дефект локализации)

Comment: @andreymal пинги произвольных участников в комментариях не работают. Чтобы локализаторы сюда пришли и подтвердили дефект локализации - надо **сначала** переделать вопрос или хотя бы поставить метку.

Comment: @PavelMayorov я не захотел так делать, потому что ещё не факт что это именно дефект локализации. А локализаторы рано или поздно всё равно пришли бы, я ж не думаю что они заглядывают только в вопросы локализации и больше никуда, это было бы слишком странно)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вопрос без счётчика голосов на закрытие в очереди на закрытие](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5151/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%81%d1%87%d1%91%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5) и да, пинги так не работают ;) Есть еще более интересная [ситуация](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41223392#41223392)

Comment: @PashaPash перевод у нас [нормальный](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263062?key=5c2b1c0cec815fa175120db002505e47), «recommend close» судя по всему только для аудитов выводится. Ибо [вот на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/53755) тоже нет никаких «recommend».

Comment: @alexolut я не уверен, что здесь были именно тревоги, следовательно не уверен что дубликат. А даже если дубликат, я продолжаю считать это как минимум дефектом)

Comment: @andreymal если это и дефект, то уж точно не локализации. По ситуации я задал [вопрос на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305297/339911). Подождём ответа как Америка проснётся.

Comment: @andreymal и кроме как тревогами это ничем не может быть для участников с менее 3к репы. Они просто не могут еще закрывать, но могут флагать с одноименной причиной.

Comment: @alexolut [вот тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5424) говорили, что им доступна очередь проверок с 2к репы. Врут что ли?

Comment: @andreymal про 2к что-то не вижу там.

Comment: @alexolut значит где-то не там видел и забыл где, или напутал что-то) Но чёт я тогда не могу найти, с какой репы становятся доступны «Сообщения низкого качества»

Comment: @alexolut а ещё мне тогда остаётся непонятно, как тогда получился этот Recommend Close? https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18297206

Comment: @andreymal ссылка, которую привел PashaPash, содержит сообщение аудита. Видимо оно обрабатывается иначе и резолюция иначе обозначается. Это я тоже указал в посте на MSE.

Comment: А, всё, понял .

Comment: Ладно, пусть тогда побудет дубликатом, но [такая ситуация](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXt1R.png) мне всё равно не особо нравится

Comment: @andreymal мне тоже. Именно поэтому я и задал вопрос на MSE.